# Estimation of a probability of marginal values of a random variable

Tags: probability, combinatorics, inequality, asymptotics

My question is related with [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/209440/selecting-columns-of-a-set-of-boolean-matrices-with-constraint-on-the-ones-in-ea) on combinatorics of 0-1-matrices from MO. Trying to obtain a (asymptotic) lower bound for $\alpha(n)$ by probabilistic approach (see, for instance, “The probabilistic method” by N. Alon and J. Spencer), I encountered the following problem.

Given a natural number $n>1$, find a bound $\alpha (n)>0$ (the bigger, the better) satisfying the following condition.

If for each positive integer $k$ and each sequence $m_1, \dots m_k$, where each $m_j$ is an integer from $0$ to $n$, we define mutually independent random variables $x_1,\dots, x_k$ such that for each $j$ a variable $x_j$ equals $1$ with probability $m_j/n$ and equals $0$ with probability $1-m_j/n$ then

$$P(x_1+\dots+x_k<\lfloor \alpha(n)(m_1+\dots+m_k)/n \rfloor)<1/n.$$

I hope that we can make $\alpha(n)\ge c/\log n$ for some $c>0$ and all sufficiently large $n$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the following

My probabilistic approach failed. To see this put $$x=x_1+\dots +x_k$$ and $$\mu=E(x)=\frac{m_1+\dots+m_k}n.$$ By [Multiplicative Chernoff Bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound#Theorem_for_multiplicative_form_of_Chernoff_bound_.28relative_error.29), for any $0<\alpha<1$ we have

$$P(x\le \alpha\mu)\le e^\frac{-(1-\alpha)^2\mu}2.$$

which suggests $$ e^\frac{-(1-\alpha)^2\mu}2<\frac 1n,$$

which implies $$\alpha<1-\sqrt{\frac{2\ln n}{\mu}},$$

which is useless for $\mu\le 2\ln n$.

This has a simple explanation for the [initial question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/209440/selecting-columns-of-a-set-of-boolean-matrices-with-constraint-on-the-ones-in-ea) from MO: if in our matrices are small number of $1$’s and a large number of $0$’s then a random choice is a bad choice for a big sum.